# Conditional evaluation of random functions

Tags: pr.probability

### Motivation

Let $(Z(x))_{x\in \mathbb{R}^n}$ be a random function (also known as random field, or random process), i.e. a collection of random variables, but also $Z\in C(\mathbb{R}^n)$ almost surely. The construction of this is not completely trivial, but let us take this as a given.

Now if one were to simulate such a random function at a discrete number of points $x_1,\dots, x_n$, one is
interested in the marginal distribution, i.e. we want to know
$$
\mathbb{E}[f(Z(x_1), \dots, Z(x_n))]
$$
for all $f$. What now happens in [Bayesian Optimization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayesian_optimization), is that we sample our random function at some point $x_0$, i.e. we obtain $Z(x_0)$, then we want to know the conditional distribution of $Z(x)$ given $Z(x_0)$. I.e.
$$
\mathbb{E}[f(Z(x))\mid Z(x_0)]
$$
This is not a huge problem if we assume $Z$ is a Guassian random function (Gaussian process) with known covariance function. But using this conditional distribution, we tend to select our next evaluation point $X_1$. I.e. $X_1$ is a random variable which is $\sigma(Z(x_0))$ measurable. If we now want to know the distribution of
$$
\mathbb{E}[f(Z(x))\mid Z(X_1), Z(x_0)]
$$
things become much more tricky, as $Z(X_1)$ is a much more complicated object than $Z(x_0)$. My hypothesis is that
$$
\mathbb{E}[f(Z(x))\mid Z(X_1), Z(x_0)]
= \bigl(y\mapsto \mathbb{E}[f(Z(x))\mid Z(y), Z(x_0)]\bigr)(X_1)
$$
as $X_1$ is completely measurable with regards to $\sigma(Z(x_0)$.

### Hypothesis

More generally I expect for a random function in $Z \in C(\mathbb{R}^n)$
$$
\mathbb{E}[f(Z(x))\mid Z(X_n),\dots, Z(X_1),Z(x_0)]
= \bigl((y_n,\dots, y_1)\mapsto \mathbb{E}[f(Z(x))\mid Z(y_n),\dots, Z(y_1),Z(x_0)]\bigr)(X_n,\dots,X_1)
$$
for $X_n$ measurable with regards to
$$
\mathcal{F}_{n-1} = \sigma(Z(x_0),Z(X_1)\dots, Z(X_{n-1})).
$$

### Progress

I have been able to prove the claim:

> Let $Z$ be an almost surely random function, $X$ be $\mathcal{F}$ measurable, then
> $$
>     \mathbb{E}[f(Z(X))\mid \mathcal{F}] = \Bigl(y\mapsto \mathbb{E}[f(Z(y))\mid \mathcal{F}]\Bigr)(X)
> $$

using the fact that the evaluation function $e(z,y) = z(y)$ is continuous and therefore measurable for continuous functions, and regular conditional distributions (I can post a proof if requested).

Now if we were not in the continuous case, we could do the following
$$
\begin{aligned}
&\mathbb{P}(Z(x) = z \mid Z(X_1) = z_1, Z(x_0) = z_0)\\
&\overset{\text{Bayes}}= \frac{\mathbb{P}(Z(X_1)=z_1 \mid Z(x)=z, Z(x_0)=z_0)\mathbb{P}(Z(x)=z, Z(x_0)=z_0)}{\mathbb{P}(Z(X_1)=z_1\mid Z(x)=z)\mathbb{P}(Z(x)=z)}
\end{aligned}
$$
and then apply the proven statement above since $X_1$ is $\sigma(Z(x), Z(x_0))$ measurable as it is already $\sigma(Z(x_0))$ measurable. Afterwards we simply use Bayes backwards to get
$$
\begin{aligned}
&\mathbb{P}(Z(x) = z \mid Z(X_1) = z_1, Z(x_0) = z_0)\\
&=\Bigl(y\mapsto \frac{\mathbb{P}(Z(y)=z_1 \mid Z(x)=z, Z(x_0)=z_0)\mathbb{P}(Z(x)=z, Z(x_0)=z_0)}{\mathbb{P}(Z(y)=z_1\mid Z(x)=z)\mathbb{P}(Z(x)=z)}\Bigr)(X_1)\\
&= \bigl(y \mapsto \mathbb{P}(Z(x) = z \mid Z(y) = z_1, Z(x_0) = z_0)\bigr)(X_1)
\end{aligned}
$$
Unfortunately, it is not quite so easy to translate this to the continuous case. $Z(x_0)\in A$ does not work, since we need to know its precise value to know $X_1$. Well, since we have that $Z$ is continuous, it might work like this. But I am unsure. Such approximating arguments seem to be very troublesome (cf. [Borel-Kolmogorov Pradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borel%E2%80%93Kolmogorov_paradox))

Does anyone already know the solution to this problem, or has any idea how to approach this? Since this is related to a common practical usecase, it seems like this should be something someone has already looked at.

Answer (score 0):

The following is a proof for the absolutely continuous case (covering Gaussian random functions)

### Lemma: Partial integration

Let $X,Z$ be random variables on polish spaces $(E_x, \mathcal{E}_x), (E_z,\mathcal{E}_z)$,
$$
    f:E_z\times E_x\to \mathbb{R}
$$
a measurable function.  Let $X$ be $\mathcal{F}$ measurable, $\kappa_{Z\mid
\mathcal{F}}$ the regular conditional distribution,
then we have for $\Pr$ almost all $\omega$
$$
    \mathbb{E}[f(Z,X) \mid \mathcal{F}](\omega)
    = \int f(z, X(\omega)) \kappa_{Z\mid \mathcal{F}}(\omega, dz)
$$
in the case $\sigma(\tilde{X})=\mathcal{F}$ this simplifies to
$$
    \mathbb{E}[f(Z,X) \mid \tilde{X}] = \int f(z, X) \kappa_{Z\mid \tilde{X}}(\tilde{X}, dz)
$$

#### Proof

left to the reader (the usual argument starting with $f=\mathbf{1}_{A\times B}$)

### Corollary: Conditional Sampling I

Let $Z$ be an almost surely random function, $X$ be $\mathcal{F}$ measurable, then
$$
    \mathbb{E}[f(Z(X))\mid \mathcal{F}] = (y\mapsto \mathbb{E}[f(Z(y))\mid \mathcal{F}])(X)
$$

#### Proof

The evaluation function
$$
    e(z,x) = z(x)
$$
is continuous on the space of continuous functions, and therefore measurable.
$f\circ e$ is then also measurable. The application of [Lemma: Partial Integration] results in
$$\begin{aligned}
    \mathbb{E}[f(Z(X))\mid \mathcal{F}](\omega)
    &=\mathbb{E}[f \circ e (Z, X) \mid \mathcal{F}](\omega)\\
    &= \int f\circ e(z, X(\omega)) \kappa_{Z\mid \mathcal{F}}(\omega, dz)\\
    &\overset{\text{Lem.}}= \Bigl(y\mapsto\int f\circ e(z, y) \kappa_{Z\mid \mathcal{F}}(\omega, dz)\Bigr)(X(\omega))\\
    &= (y\mapsto \mathbb{E}[f(Z(y))\mid \mathcal{F}])(X)(\omega)
\end{aligned}$$
Where we use Klenke (2014, Thm. 8.38)
for the last equation and all equalities are true for almost all $\omega$.

### Conditional sampling Lemma

Let $Z$ be a random function from $\mathbb{R}^d$ to $\mathbb{R}^m$.  Assume
that for all $\lambda$ we have that $Y, \tilde{X}, X, Z(\lambda)$ are random
variables with joint densities on $\mathbb{R},\mathbb{R}^n, \mathbb{R}^d, \mathbb{R}$ such
that $X$ is $\sigma(\tilde{X})$ measurable.
Then we have
$$
    \Pr(Y\in A \mid Z(X), \tilde{X})
    = \Bigl(\lambda \mapsto \Pr(Y\in A \mid Z(\lambda), \tilde{X})\Bigr)(X)
$$
and $Y, \tilde{X}, Z(X)$ have joint density.

#### Proof

First we want to prove that $Z(X)$ also has a joint density with the other variables.
For this we use the regular conditional distribution to get
$$
    \Pr(Z(X) \in A, (Y, \tilde{X}))
    = \int_B \underbrace{
        \Pr(Z(X) \in A \mid (Y, \tilde{X}) = (y,x))
    }_{=\mathbb{E}[\mathbf{1}_A(Z(X))\mid (Y, \tilde{X}) = (y,x)]} \Pr_{Y,\tilde{X}}(dy, dx)
$$
which we can now apply the Corollary to get
$$
    \underbrace{\mathbb{E}[\mathbf{1}_A(Z(X)) \mid Y, \tilde{X}]}_{=: h(Y, \tilde{X})}
    = \Bigl(
        \lambda \mapsto \underbrace{
            \mathbb{E}[\mathbf{1}_A(Z(\lambda))\mid Y, \tilde{X}]
        }_{=:h_\lambda(Y,\tilde{X})}
    \Bigr)(\underbrace{X}_{=:g(\tilde{X})})
    = h_{g(\tilde{X})}(Y, \tilde{X})
$$
where we use the Doob-Dynkin factorization lemma repeatedly and the fact that
$X$ is $\tilde{X}$ measurable. We therefore have for $(Y,\tilde{X})$ almost
all $y,x$
$$\begin{aligned}
    h(y,x)
    &= h_{g(x)}(y,x)
    \\
    &= \mathbb{E}[\mathbf{1}_A(Z(g(x)))\mid Y,\tilde{X} = (y,x)]
    \\
    &= \int_A \varphi_{Z(g(x))\mid Y, \tilde{X}}(z\mid y,x) dz
\end{aligned}$$
Putting things together we have
$$
    \Pr(Z(X) \in A, (Y, \tilde{X}))
    = \int_B
        \int_A \varphi_{Z(g(x))\mid Y, \tilde{X}}(z\mid y,x)dz
    \varphi_{Y,\tilde{X}}(y,x) dy dx.
$$
This proves we have the joint density
$$
    \varphi_{Z(X), Y, \tilde{X}}(z,y,x)
    = \varphi_{Z(g(x))\mid Y, \tilde{X}}(z\mid y,x) \varphi_{Y,\tilde{X}}(y,x).
$$
And thus the conditional density is also well defined and given by
$$
    \varphi_{Z(X)\mid Y, \tilde{X}}(z\mid y, x)
    = \frac{\varphi_{Z(X), Y, \tilde{X}}(z,y,x)}{\varphi_{Y,\tilde{X}}(y,x)}
    = \varphi_{Z(g(x))\mid Y, \tilde{X}}(z\mid y,x)
$$
We now use this fact to reason with Bayes arguments, that
$$\begin{aligned}
    \varphi_{Y\mid Z(X), \tilde{X}}(y\mid z, x)
    &= \frac{\varphi_{Y, Z(X), \tilde{X}}(y, z, x)}{\varphi_{Z(X), \tilde{X}}(z,x)}
    \\
    &= \frac{
        \varphi_{Z(X) \mid Y, \tilde{X}}(z \mid y, x)\varphi_{Y,X}(y,x)
    }{\varphi_{Z(X)\mid \tilde{X}}(z\mid x)\varphi_{\tilde{X}}(x)}
    \\
    &=
    \frac{
        \varphi_{Z(g(x)) \mid Y, \tilde{X}}(z \mid y, x)\varphi_{Y,X}(y,x)
    }{\varphi_{Z(g(x))\mid \tilde{X}}(z\mid x)\varphi_{\tilde{X}}(x)}
    \\
    &=\varphi_{Y\mid Z(g(x)), \tilde{X}}(y\mid z, x)
\end{aligned}$$
Which finally implies our claim
$$\begin{aligned}
    \Pr(Y\in A \mid Z(X), \tilde{X} = (z,x))
    &= \int_A \varphi_{Y\mid Z(X), \tilde{X}}(y\mid z, x) dy
    \\
    &= \int_A \varphi_{Y\mid Z(g(x)), \tilde{X}}(y\mid z, x) dy
    \\
    &= \Bigl(\lambda \mapsto \int_A \varphi_{Y\mid Z(\lambda), \tilde{X}}(y\mid z, x) dy\Bigr)
    (g(x))
    \\
    &= \Bigl(\lambda \mapsto \Pr(Y\in A \mid Z(\lambda), \tilde{X}=(z,x))\Bigr)(g(x)),
\end{aligned}$$
i.e.
$$
    \Pr(Y\in A \mid Z(X), \tilde{X})
    = \Bigl(
        \lambda \mapsto \Pr(Y\in A \mid Z(\lambda), \tilde{X})
    \Bigr)(\underbrace{g(\tilde{X})}_{=X}).
$$

## Conditional Sampling Theorem

Let $Z$ be a random function from $\mathbb{R}^d$ to $\mathbb{R}^m$ with an
existing density function.  Let $x_1\in \mathbb{R}^d$ and define
$$
    \mathcal{F}_n = \sigma(Z(X_i): i\le n)
$$
where $X_1=x_1$ and $X_{n+1}$ is $\mathcal{F}_n$ measurable. Then we have
for measurable functions $f$
$$\begin{aligned}
    &\mathbb{E}[f(Z(X_{n+1}))\mid \mathcal{F}_n]
    \\
    &= \Bigl(
        (y_1,\dots,y_{n+1})\mapsto \mathbb{E}[f(Z(y_{n+1})) \mid Z(y_1), \dots, Z(y_n)]
    \Bigr)(X_1,\dots, X_{n+1})
\end{aligned}$$
and for any $m\in \mathbb{N}$ the joint density of $Z(X_1),\dots, Z(X_{n+1}), Z(\lambda_1),\dots, Z(\lambda_m)$ exists for any $\lambda_i\in\mathbb{R}^d$.

#### Proof

Let us first address the density problem. By induction we have that
$$
    \underbrace{Z(X_1),\dots, Z(X_n), Z(\lambda_1),\dots, Z(\lambda_{m-1})}_{=:\tilde{X}}Z(\lambda_m)
$$
has joint density. Then by the conditional sampling Lemma, $\tilde{X}, Z(X_{n+1})$
have joint density, as $X_{n+1}$ is $\sigma(\tilde{X})$ measurable. So we have
$$
    Z(X_1),\dots, Z(X_{n+1}), Z(\lambda_1),\dots, Z(\lambda_{m-1})
$$
have joint density. As $m\in \mathbb{N}$ was arbitrary, we have this for any $m-1$.

Now to the actual statement: As $X_{n+1}$ is $\mathcal{F}_n$ measurable, we
first remove it using the Corollary, resulting
in
$$
    \mathbb{E}[f(Z(X_{n+1}))\mid \mathcal{F}_n] = (y_{n+1}\mapsto \underbrace{\mathbb{E}[f(Z(y_{n+1}))\mid \mathcal{F}_n]}_{(*)})(X_{n+1})
$$
we now look at $(*)$ and define $Y:=f(Z(y_{n+1}))$ and $\tilde{X} =
(Z(X_1), \dots, Z(X_{n-1}))$, we know that everything has joint density
so by the conditional sampling Lemma
$$
    \mathbb{E}[Y\mid Z(X_n), \tilde{X}]
    = (y_n\mapsto \mathbb{E}[Y\mid Z(y_n), \tilde{X}])(X_n)
$$
The remaining $X_i$ can be moved out with the same argument using
$$
    \tilde{X}= (Z(X_1),\dots Z(X_{i-1}),Z(y_{i+1}),\dots,Z(y_n)).
$$